# psd file format

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, photoshop, psd

I am attempting to find documentation of the psd file format so I can read in a .psd and then save out the individual layers as files, along with do other modifications. Does anyone know of any document in on the .psd file format? (Just for reference, I will be writing this in C++)

If there are any code examples of loading a .psd file in C++ then I would appreciate them being linked.

(Please not turn this into a "just use XXX software". This is not homework, or anything related to that. I am doing this because I think it will be a fun project to work on. I will ask for posts to be down voted if this happens.)

Comment: What I'd do is look for [open source](http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/list?q=psd_codec) versions of [this](http://www.ardfry.com/psd-codec/). EDIT: Wait, here's [one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/PhotoshopPreviewHandler.aspx), as seen on [My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/04/01/adobe-photoshop-psd-preview-handler-free-download/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will *not* be a fun project, the .psd format is **big**. It incorporates every feature Adobe has put into Photoshop over many years.

I believe the specification can be had from Adobe, but they don't just hand it out to the public. You'll have to contact them and jump through some hoops first.

Comment: I think you can find the most recent specifications over here http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

Comment: @northsea it's been many years since I had anything to do with the .psd format, it appears they've decided there's nothing to lose by making the spec public. Thanks for the link. The first part of my answer still applies.

Answer (score 42):

There's also some Objective-C code on [GitHub](https://github.com/kjk/xee/blob/master/XeePhotoshopLoader.m) (should be easily understandable for anyone with a C++ background), also source of this gem, which appears to sum it up nicely:

> At this point, I'd like to take a moment to speak to you about the Adobe PSD format.
>   PSD is not a good format. PSD is not even a bad format. Calling it such would be an
>   insult to other bad formats, such as PCX or JPEG. No, PSD is an abysmal format. Having
>   worked on this code for several weeks now, my hate for PSD has grown to a raging fire
>   that burns with the fierce passion of a million suns.
>   If there are two different ways of doing something, PSD will do both, in different
>   places. It will then make up three more ways no sane human would think of, and do those
>   too. PSD makes inconsistency an art form. Why, for instance, did it suddenly decide
>   that *these* particular chunks should be aligned to four bytes, and that this alignement
>   should *not* be included in the size? Other chunks in other places are either unaligned,
>   or aligned with the alignment included in the size. Here, though, it is not included.
>   Either one of these three behaviours would be fine. A sane format would pick one. PSD,
>   of course, uses all three, and more.
>   Trying to get data out of a PSD file is like trying to find something in the attic of
>   your eccentric old uncle who died in a freak freshwater shark attack on his 58th
>   birthday. That last detail may not be important for the purposes of the simile, but
>   at this point I am spending a lot of time imagining amusing fates for the people
>   responsible for this Rube Goldberg of a file format.
>   Earlier, I tried to get a hold of the latest specs for the PSD file format. To do this,
>   I had to apply to them for permission to apply to them to have them consider sending
>   me this sacred tome. This would have involved faxing them a copy of some document or
>   other, probably signed in blood. I can only imagine that they make this process so
>   difficult because they are intensely ashamed of having created this abomination. I
>   was naturally not gullible enough to go through with this procedure, but if I had done
>   so, I would have printed out every single page of the spec, and set them all on fire.
>   Were it within my power, I would gather every single copy of those specs, and launch
>   them on a spaceship directly into the sun.
>
> PSD is not my favourite file format.

Just so you are warned. :)

Comment: I've seen that quote before, and I believe every word.

Answer (score 8):

The PSD file format specification as written by Adobe is here;

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/

*Last update: June 2012*. As far as I know this is the best available source about the PSD file format even there are few mistakes.

First I recommend starting by dividing PSD into blocks.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

MyPSD::CPSD class is a C++ class that can load images saved in Adobe's Photoshop native format. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10398/Import-Adobe-Photoshop-psd-images

Answer (score 1):

MolecularMatters psd_sdk seems like a good library to take inspiration form: https://github.com/MolecularMatters/psd_sdk

It allows to read layers from a .psd file and much more.