# Working with .psd file in QT

Tags: qt, psd

Is there any provision to work with .PSD file in Qt ? I need to import a existing .PSD file and write an image in one of the layer and save back to .PSD file. Can it possible in qt ? any library supports this

Comment: No. You should look for a library for your programming language instead.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355708/psd-file-format

Answer (score -1):

you should try GIMP if you are on linux.You can easily edit .psd files in GIMP.It fully supports .psd files.